# Thevenin equation of a circuit with two voltage sources, one on an open circuit

Tags: thevenin

I am incredibly sorry, as I'm sure this specific example has been asked before, but I missed the class on it and the professor hasn't yet uploaded the video to his website. I need to know how to find the thevenin equivalent of this circuit:
[image: 1]

A lot of the resources online don't seem to cover this specific example, and while I understand how to do it for one source, or sources that are in sequence, the parallel is tripping me up. What really confuses me is how I should be measuring the source connected to the open circuit. I would really appreciate the help.

Since this is for a lab, I need to measure the equivalent resistance, the open circuit voltage, and the closed circuit current.

Comment: Can you tell what would be the voltage between A and B? Without the load.

Comment: Well, it should be a current divider on the left, making it 5v, but I'm not sure if it'd be 6 on the other side, and since I missed the class, I don't know what it'd be. My best guess would be -1V

Comment: You are correct 1V (or -1V, depending on the polarity). So this would be the Thevenin voltage. The Thevenin resistance is calculated the very same way as with a single supply.

Comment: So with setting the voltage sources to be short circuits, it'd be 510||510+100 which would be 355 ohm as the equivalent resistor?

Comment: Correct.  And the mental model of setting the voltage sources to short circuits (or to 0V -- same thing) is a good one to use going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by redrawing the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmp7jX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then use a source transformation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7sCnf.png)</sup>

Combine the resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f02r1a.png)</sup>

Transform back:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv4Ll8.png)</sup>

Finally combine the series components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwPU4y.png)</sup>

Comment: You went a really hard way.

Comment: Could you explain the two source conversions in more detail? Also, with eugene's help I managed to do this by myself, can I answer my own question?

Comment: The source conversions are just the thevenin/norton equivalents of a voltage source in series / current source in parallel with a resistor

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I thought it was a good step-by-step demonstration.  Yes, it was sliced very fine -- but sometimes that's what a beginner needs to see.

Comment: @Ngoldman: Yes you can answer your own question.  If you can make sure to include some detail rather than just a number it would be helpful to the next guy who comes along with a similar problem.